# My discord music bot isn't joining my channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've been following a guide on youtube, and I have logic in place that recognizes that I need to join a voice channel first, but when I am in the channel and I run the !play  command, nothing happens. I set some print statements to help debug things, it runs the `print('hello')`, but it doesn't print the second `print('helllo')`. Any thoughts here on what's going on?

```
@commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p","playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
async def play(self, ctx, *args):
    query = " ".join(args)
    # 
    voice = ctx.author.voice
    if voice is None:
        #you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
        await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")

    elif self.is_paused:
        self.vc.resume()

    else:
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        print('hello')
        self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()
        print('helllo')
        song = self.search_yt(query)
        if type(song) == type(True):
            print('alamasaka')
            await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
        else:
            print('tehe')
            await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
            self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
            
            if self.is_playing == False:
                print('nickie poop')
                await self.play_music(ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the first  `print` but not the second one, then the bot is getting a loop while connecting to the channel. This happened to me when I accidentaly gave repeated information to the bot (`await ctx.send(attachments=[file, file])`)... maybe it's related to that.

EDIT: To confirm this theory, wait around 2 minutes and, if you get a disconnect error, then this is what is happening.